# Connect database using query to a datatable in vb codes

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

I want to connect a table from a database using select query. The connection string is already made on the `web.config` page.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="IntranetConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=nanana\sql5;Initial Catalog=Intranet;User ID=intra_admin;password=jimfool" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I want to make a function called GetList where I can use it whenever i want to bind the information. this is my vb code

```
Public Function GetList() As DataTable
    Dim Query As String
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Query = "Select * FROM Intranet_Gn_ISCoordinators"

    'I need to write something here ..
    'dt = 
    Return dt
End Function
```

I am biggener, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [SqlDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2):

```
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Function GetList() As DataTable

    Dim Query As String = "Select * FROM Intranet_Gn_ISCoordinators"
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()

    Using adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(Query, ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IntranetConnectionString"].ConnectionString)
        adapter.Fill(dt)
        return dt
    End Using

End Function
```

---

*As an aside, I realise the query may have just been an example, but `SELECT *` is generally a bad idea in production code. Explicitly list the columns you want*

Comment: It gives me "Cannot be converted to system.data.sqlclient.SqlConnection ! what shell I do?!

Comment: I changed the [] to () and the error has gone. but the problem is in adapter.Fill(dt) ! it gives me Value cannot be Null. please help me

Comment: Added `= New DataTable()` to get rid of the dt cannot be null problem.